# Using React with ejs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ejs

I have a front-end that is built using React states that is meant to adapt based on user action. However, my front-end React is also meant to show and allow manipulation of my server-side data. Currently my view engine is EJS, and I am using it to display data. As a broad example:

```
  return (<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-7">
    <ul>
      <li><span class="point">Name:</span> <%= user.profile.name %> </li>
      <li><span class="point">Email:</span> <%= user.email %> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>);
```

I have established that I cannot mix these ejs `<%=` tags with React. This makes manipulating the data a challenge. Unless I redo my UI in jQuery, I'm not sure how to proceed.

I have looked at [this React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html) for passing data, but upon testing it the result does not allow me to make cross-origin calls, and my MongoDB is stored on MongoLab. Thus, I am relegated to using EJS to call my data.

With the restrictions of using React with EJS, I am puzzled over what solutions I have to implement a UI tool like React with server-side data.

Comment: Do you have node.js backend?

Comment: I have an express environment set up.

Comment: This makes no sense. React *already does templating* through the JSX `{...}` notation, why do you needs templating on top of that? Take a half hour to run through https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html, which is well worth your time, so that you understand how "client vs server" isn't a distinction React should be concerned with. You make React build the UI. Not some other templating engine.

Comment: It makes sense if you want to incrementally add React to an existing, large project that uses EJS (which React uses as a selling point).

Comment: It also makes sense if you are implementing generators and need templatized react components.

Comment: No one said how you would properly use React without EJS, and I'm trying to figure it out. I assume you'd need to rework your server calls from the client so that the client gets the react template info rather than the whole rendered page, right?

Comment: I get it now.  if anyone wants an explanation, comment or msg me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In express:

```
res.render('view', {user: myUser});
```

In EJS before the app's js bundle:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var userFromServer =<%-JSON.stringify(user)%>
</script>
```

Use `userFromServer` in your react code.

Answer (score 1):

If ur using express then that would be obvious your entry point would be something like app.ejs;
To have a react component you would need to change the extension to app.jsx as an entry point, It worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

you can use `react` with `babel.js` without webpack .but it may not be a good solution. but it works

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<!-- for imported scripts -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
 const { React, ReactDOM } = window;
 function App(){
   return (<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-7">
    <ul>
      <li><span class="point">Name:</span> <%= user.profile.name %> </li>
      <li><span class="point">Email:</span> <%= user.email %> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>)
 }
 ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
</script>
```